# Regression tree with nested data repeated in time (GLMERTREE, REEMTREE or REEMCTREE)

Tags: r, generalized-linear-model, lme4-nlme, cart, party

I work on the predation of seeds by insects (carabidae), and I am particularly interested in the effect of community composition on predation. I would like to know if the best predation rates are associated with one (or two) species, or with a complex assemblage of species.

For this reason I was interested in the regression tree. My data set consists of my response variable (predation rate between 0 and 1),

[image]

and the abundance of each species of beetle caught. 
The structure of my data is hierarchical, I have follow-ups in several projects (with slightly different protocols) in which several fields are followed. Field is nested in project. And the fields are tracked over time. 
I found several regression tree methods that include random effects: `REEMtree`, `REEMctree` and `glmertree`.

I wish I'd known:

1. if one of these methods is more appropriate than the others to my data
2. how to write the random effect. I think it's: `1|Project/Time/Field`

While trying the different methods I met some interrogations:

3. The tree obtained with `REEMtree` is constantly changing. Is there a reason for that?
4. With `REEMctree` the values predicted in my tree are no longer limited between 0 and 1
5. With `glmertree` is it necessary to have a treatment variable? Or can I write:

   ```
   gt <- glmertree(TP_viola ~  1 |(1 | Data/Mois/Parcelle)| Harpalus + ... +
                   Pterostichus, data = Compilation_zone_ap_genre_CP, family = "binomial")
   ```

Is there a way to include my predation rate in the form of `cbind` (consumed seeds, exposed seeds - consumed seeds). Because the number of exposed seeds change according to the projects.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't got a full answer but some comments with partial answers:

- The `glmertree()` function does not require a treatment effect or any other kind of slope parameter in each node of the tree. Thus, it is ok to use the tree to capture only changes in a piecewise constant mean - as you do in your formula.
- If you don't get a response about the `REEMtree`/`REEMctree` part, I recommend contacting the lead author Jeff Simonoff directly. I don't think he follows StackExchange.
- Your response `TP_viola` is a proportion but you use `family = binomial` which would usually expect a binary factor response. I would at least try whether the results are sufficiently stable when using something like `factor(TP_viola > 0.5)`. Of course, it's not a good idea to binarize the response when more detailed data is available - but it might be useful as a robustness check. But it's also not good to simply go with a binomial model when you have a proportion. In the absence of random effects I would recommend beta regression but I don't think there is a readily available software combining beta regression, recursive partitioning, and mixed effects. Building blocks for this are around in R but would require some work...

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Concerning the binomial family, I didn't think it only managed binary data and that would lead to a loss of information. 
Using `factor(TP_viola>0.5)` the structure of the tree is modified, but the variables selected are the same (except a new one). Maybe another possibility is to use `lmertree` (family: gaussian), it gives me a different structure, but the same variables are selected. In addition, by using `lmertree` I can use `stabletree`, while with glmertree (binomial) I get error messages.

Comment: For REEMtree, I solved the instability problem by disabling automatic(?) cross-validation, and choosing the optimal cp myself. However, I have not made any progress on the values predicted in my tree which are not included in 0 and 1 and I will contact Jeff Simonoff as you advise me. Thank you.